# What Java application is available to stress-test a virtual machine?

Tags: performance, profiling, computer-science, kernel

I am interested in ways to stress-test as well as benchmark the [SANOS](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/index.htm) operating system kernel.

Comment: The goal is to figure out where it breaks...

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure if this is suitable for kernel testing you may want to have a look at
[SPECjbb2005](http://www.spec.org/jbb2005/)

> ""*SPECjbb2005 (Java Server Benchmark) is
>   SPEC's benchmark for evaluating the
>   performance of server side Java. Like
>   its predecessor, SPECjbb2000,
>   SPECjbb2005 evaluates the performance
>   of server side Java by emulating a
>   three-tier client/server system (with
>   emphasis on the middle tier).* **The
>   benchmark exercises the
>   implementations of the JVM (Java
>   Virtual Machine), JIT (Just-In-Time)
>   compiler, garbage collection, threads
>   and some aspects of the operating
>   system. It also measures the
>   performance of CPUs, caches, memory
>   hierarchy and the scalability of
>   shared memory processors (SMPs).**
>   *SPECjbb2005 provides a new enhanced
>   workload, implemented in a more*
>   object-oriented manner to reflect how
>   real-world applications are designed
>   and introduces new features such as
>   XML processing and BigDecimal
>   computations to make the benchmark a
>   more realistic reflection of today's
>   applications.""